# Github Repo Error push and adding remote ssh error

Tags: github, repository

error: remote origin already exists.

getting above error when adding remote repo

getting below error when trying push to main branch

ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I tried everything nothing seems to work